# Spring Scheduled annotation how does it work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I have created a function in java.That function should run on every day mid night

```
//My function this function is within UpdateService Class
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?")
public static void UpdateFn() {
    try {
        System.out.println("-----------Background Task Running----------------");
        //code to update some data every day
        System.out.println("-----------Background Task Ending----------------");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//My xml configuration
 <task:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="UpdateTask" class="com.ss.utility.UpdateService"></bean>
  </beans>
```

But i not working as expected.Sometime it executed and sometime not.Any solution for this.

Spring version is 4

Comment: It won't work on static methods.

Comment: Thank you i willa change and check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoundn't use static method for this. Try to use following code:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?")
public void UpdateFn() {
    try {
        System.out.println("-----------Background Task Running----------------");
        //code to update some data every day
        System.out.println("-----------Background Task Ending----------------");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```