# @EnableScheduling doesn't seem to work in Java 1.7 code

Tags: java, spring

Am using Java 1.7 and Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE

Have a property file in the following location:

```
/opt/myapp.properties
```

This only contains the following entry:

```
name = true
```

Java code

```
@EnableScheduling
@Controller
public class PropertiesUtil {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000) 
    public String getPropertyValue() throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStreamReader in = null;
        String value = null;
        try {
             in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/opt/myapp/app.properties"), "UTF-8");
             properties.load(in);
             value =  properties.getProperty("name");
             logger.info("\n\n\t\tName: " + value + "\n\n");
        } 
        finally {
            if (null != in) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException ex) {}
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

My Rest Endpoint:

```
@RestController
public class PropertyController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/checkProperty", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> checkProperty() throws IOException {
        PropertiesUtil propertiesUtil = new PropertiesUtil();
        String value = propertiesUtil.getPropertyValue();
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Check for Property", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

When I build this mvn clean install and deploy it as a war file, I have to explicitly hit my rest endpoint for this to work (to view the "name = true" inside my log file)...

Am trying to have Spring Web App check the `/opt/myapp/app.properties` file every 10 seconds using the `@EnableScheduling` and `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)` annotations.

Right now, I have to manually hit my Rest Endpoint to view the property's value.

Comment: remove `static` qualifier from the method - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173165/spring-scheduled-annotation-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @senseiwu - thanks but its still not working - I edited the post with static keyword removed and updated the Rest Controller.

Comment: try adding `@Scheduled` on a configuration class or use something like Spring boot  and add it there

Comment: Nearly all of the `@Enable` annotations have to be applied to configuration classes.

Comment: Can’t  use Spring Boot as this is a Spring Framework app

Comment: Chrylis - can you provide me with some example code for the configuration class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by creating a Spring Config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class PropertiesUtilConfig {

    @Bean
    public PropertiesUtil task() {
        return new PropertiesUtil();
    }

}
```

---

PropertiesUtil does not need the @EnableScheduling annotation just @Controller:

```
@Controller
public class PropertiesUtil {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000) 
    public String getPropertyValue() throws IOException { 
        // inline code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need split your method. In schedule, It need not have return. I mean It need:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000) 
    public void getProperty(){
        String value = caculateValueFromProperties();
        //do something you want. Bellow my example.
        log.info("Value after calculate "+value);

    }
```

//split new method

```
 public String caculateValueFromProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
            InputStreamReader in = null;
            String value = null;
            try {
                 in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/opt/myapp/app.properties"), "UTF-8");
                 properties.load(in);
                 value =  properties.getProperty("name");
                 logger.info("\n\n\t\tName: " + value + "\n\n");
            } 
            finally {
                if (null != in) {
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException ex) {}
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
```

> The methods annotated with @Scheduled must have void returns and must
>   not have any arguments. This is because of it's periodic nature where
>   passing an argument or receiving a return value won't make much sense.